# How can I get a specific JSON Array from the response using Retrofit2 and GSON?

Tags: android, api, gson, retrofit2

I am trying to retrieve some data from in JSON format using Retrofit and only want a specific array form the response. How can I do this using GSON ? For example, in the example below, only the 'articles' array is wanted.

```
status: "ok",
totalResults: 970843,
articles: [
{
   ...,
   ...,
   ...
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a custom deserializer for this particular case, or (and that second option is what I will describe) have a more generic solution that requires a bit more effort to put in, but will pay off nicely in the long run, as you would be able to apply it for other similar use cases. This is my favorite approach, I came across it on GitHub (I am not the inventor) - and have adopted for self as well - you can inspect the code and the project to understand how it all works together - [project link](https://github.com/fabioCollini/ArchitectureComponentsDemo/blob/master/api/src/main/java/it/codingjam/github/api/util/DenvelopingConverter.kt)

Below I extracted the relevant pieces:

> 1. Create a special converter factory as such:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Converter
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import java.lang.reflect.Type

/**
 * A [Converter.Factory] which removes unwanted wrapping envelopes from API
 * responses.
 */
class DenvelopingConverter(internal val gson: Gson) : Converter.Factory() {

    override fun responseBodyConverter(
            type: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>?, retrofit: Retrofit?): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {

        // This converter requires an annotation providing the name of the payload in the envelope;
        // if one is not supplied then return null to continue down the converter chain.
        val payloadName = getPayloadName(annotations) ?: return null

        val adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type))
        return Converter<ResponseBody, Any> { body ->
            try {
                val jsonReader = gson.newJsonReader(body.charStream())
                jsonReader.beginObject()
                while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                    if (payloadName == jsonReader.nextName()) {
                        return@Converter adapter.read(jsonReader)
                    } else {
                        jsonReader.skipValue()
                    }
                }
                return@Converter null
            } finally {
                body.close()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getPayloadName(annotations: Array<Annotation>?): String? {
        if (annotations == null) {
            return null
        }
        for (annotation in annotations) {
            if (annotation is EnvelopePayload) {
                return annotation.value
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

> 2. Create this annotation class

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class EnvelopePayload(val value: String = "")
```

> 3. In your retrofit builder, add the converter you created in step 1

```
  return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(DenvelopingConverter(gson))
```

> 4. In your retrofit interface, use the @EnvelopePayload you created in step 2 to filter the elements you want, in your case, "articles", like so

```
interface MyService {

    @EnvelopePayload("articles")
    @GET("whatever")
    //fun search....
}
```

That's it, enjoy!